# how to create buttons with a for loop in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Ok so I've been trying to get a level select scene working for Custom levels (levels that the user created), so i need to have a button for each created level, and i have been trying to do it with a for loop, but only one button shows up. here is my code:

```
-(void)AddLevelButtons{
    NSArray *levels = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    levels = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:CustomPath      error:nil];
    LevelCount = (int)[levels count];
    for (int counter= 0;counter<LevelCount;counter++) {
        CCButton *tempButton;
        tempButton=[CCButton buttonWithTitle:@"" spriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"othercategory.png"]];
        tempButton.block= ^(id sender) {
            GameScene *GameNode = [[GameScene alloc]initWithPlistName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomLevel_%d",counter]withObjIndex:counter];
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:LevelEditorNode.scene withTransition:[CCTransition transitionFadeWithDuration:.5f]];
        };
        tempButton.positionType=CCPositionTypeNormalized;
        tempButton.position = ccp(counter+2/5,.5f);
        [ScrollingNode addChild:tempButton];
   }
}
```

I thought that maybe both buttons were created, and they just had the same position, but i set a breakpoint, and only one button is created.

Comment: errr .... show the loop please !

Comment: sorry about that... I copied it wrong.

Comment: If i understand correctly your last sentence, the loop runs only once, ie LevelCount == 1 !  maybe you want to check that, and if it is, why it is so. Also, a note : prefer levelCount, gameNode, levelEditorNode and scrollingNode as spelling ... makes your code easier to read for all here trying to help. Keep the UpperCase for class names. I also dont get why you are creating the gameNode object : it is not used anywhere. Finally, make certain that ScrollingNode's size is set.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was that i didn't set the contentSize of the scrollingNode, sorry about the naming (x